# Set log level for chrome logs in ruby

Tags: ruby, google-chrome, logging, watir, console.log

I'm trying to assert that there is no mixed content in a website. I have set the log level equal to 1 in the chrome switches , but i m still unable to retrieve warning messages from the browser, here is the code im using.

```
browser = Watir::Browser.new :chrome,
                         switches: %w[--disable-gpu --no-sandbox
                  --disable-prompt-on-repost
                  --windows-size=3200x1800
                  --log-level=1]
console_log = browser.driver.manage.logs.get (:browser)
```

What am i doing wrong? or there is other way to set this log level to capture errors and warnings?

Answer (score 1):

Work done ,, just changing the way i was passing the settings to the browsr is working

```
    options = Selenium::WebDriver::Chrome::Options.new
options.add_argument('--disable-infobars')
options.add_argument('--disable-gpu')
options.add_argument('--no-sandbox')
options.add_argument('--disable-prompt-on-repost')
options.add_argument('--user-agent="Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 6.0.1; SAMSUNG SM-G925F Build/MMB29K) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) SamsungBrowser/4.0 Chrome/44.0.2403.133 Mobile Safari/537.36"')
```